# How to access the 'value' keys in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am creating multiple meta boxes in WordPress, and I want the user to be able to toggle certain boxes on or off.

So, they click a radio button (in a separate meta box), update the options, and an additional meta box attached to that radio value will appear.

So it basically goes from one meta box (the selector box) to two meta boxes (the selector box, AND the new box they just selected).

In my code, you can create a meta box by setting something like this up (this is the radio box where the user selects for other meta boxes to toggle on/off):

```
// Create meta box that gives user ability to select additional meta box, 
// which will then show upon saving the post

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'meta_box_id',
    'title' => 'Box title',
    'pages' => array('page'),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'low',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Select:',
            'id' => $prefix . 'meta_box_id',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'options' => array(
                array('name' => 'Value 1', 'value' => 'value_one'),
                array('name' => 'Value 2', 'value' => 'value_two'),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here is what it looks like in WordPress:

[image: Box title in WordPress]

And here is another meta box that, once selected in the meta box above (let's say value_one is selected), will appear on the post screen:

```
// This meta box will only show if 'value_one' is selected from 
the radio box above

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'standard_lead',
    'title' => 'Standard Lead',
    'pages' => array('page'),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'lead' => 'value_one',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => $prefix . 'standard_title',
            'name' => 'Lead Title',
            'desc' => 'The title of your Standard Lead',
            'width' => '100'
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'id' => $prefix . 'standard_content',
            'name' => 'Lead Content',
            'desc' => 'The content of your Standard Lead (you can use HTML)',
            'width' => '100'
        )
    )
);
```

The important piece from that code is this:

```
'lead' => 'value_one',
```

My plan was to have the ['lead'] value (from the meta box code directly above) to match the ['value'] value (from the radio meta box), so they could be connected, and then test with an IF statement to make sure they equal the same thing, and then display ONLY if they both equal value_one.

The function below is what actually adds the meta boxes into WordPress. Within that function, I tried creating this IF statement to match those two together:

```
if($this->_meta_box['value'] == $this->_meta_box['lead'])
```

but it doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to target ['value'] as it's nested within multiple arrays (or I assume, is the problem).

Here's the full function:

```
function add_meta_boxes()
{
    $this->_meta_box['context'] = empty($this->_meta_box['context']) ? 'normal' : $this->_meta_box['context'];
    $this->_meta_box['priority'] = empty($this->_meta_box['priority']) ? 'high' : $this->_meta_box['priority'];

    foreach($this->_meta_box['pages'] as $page)
    {
        if($this->_meta_box['value'] == $this->_meta_box['lead'])
        {
            // adds meta box to WP
            add_meta_box($this->_meta_box['id'], $this->_meta_box['title'], array(&$this, 'show_meta_boxes'), $page, $this->_meta_box['context'], $this->_meta_box['priority']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$this->_meta_box`? What are the contents of that array?

Comment: @jeremyharris I made a foreach 'foreach($meta_boxes as $meta_box)' that takes each instance of 'meta_boxes[]', and use that to pull values from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access multi-dimensional array values in PHP, use the following syntax:

```
$arrayVar['key1']['key2'];
```

So to access the 'value' keys in your first array, do it like so:

```
$this->_meta_box['fields']['options'];
/* returns 
array(
  array('name' => 'Value 1', 'value' => 'value_one'),
  array('name' => 'Value 2', 'value' => 'value_two'),
);
*/
// to get the first option's value
$this->_meta_box['fields']['options'][0]['value'];
// to get the second option's value
$this->_meta_box['fields']['options'][1]['value'];
```

Comment: That is helping me understand a little better. But when I changed the IF statement to

`if($this->_meta_box['fields']['options'][0]['value'] == $this->_meta_box['lead'])`

...nothing changed. I think I am missing something still. If you'd like to see the full code file to better wrap your head around this, I can provide it.

Comment: I'm maybe a little unclear on what you're trying to do. I get that you're trying to show a meta box based on a selected radio option. How do you get the selected radio value, and where are you storing it? This is PHP code so the when the user selects an option it needs to do something in order to change it. You might be better off using JS to show/hide the meta boxes.

Comment: Yes, you got it. And that is exactly what I'm trying to do: get the value to use in the IF statement. I thought it was stored in the ['value'] array, and I could just call it with what you suggested. But I think I am doing something wrong, or missing something (clearly, I'm a little on the novice side of PHP). The JS solution does sound more elegant, I will research to see how this can be done as an alternative (if you have any suggestions, that'd be great too). Thanks for the help so far Jeremy!

Comment: It might be best to ask that as another question if you can't figure it out, and include the HTML markup that is generated by WP. Hope you figure it out!